# WDK compiled driver will not install on device in Win 7 x64

Tags: driver, 64-bit, wdk

I am completely new to both programing and driver programing.

I am trying to get a WDK sample driver to load, specifically the KBFILTR. I am able to compile it in the win7 x64 free build environment, I'm including the `wdfcoinstallerMMmmmm.dll`, and making sure I am in test mode for test-signed drivers and the `Kbfiltr.sys` has a test signature.

When I try to install it via device manager to my chosen keyboard I am getting a `no compatible driver in folder error please verify compatibility with x64`.

At work on a win_7x86, I can compile it in the proper environment and install it without such an error. Any info written for a newb will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're new to programming and you're starting with device drivers?!  Not what anyone would recommend.

Comment: which coinstaller did you use? what inf did you use?

Answer (score 0):

The following development environments are currently supported  on Windows:

MinGW (32 bit) or MinGW-w64. To compile a library that is both 32 and 64 bit compatible, you should use a version of MinGW-w64 that supports both -m32 and -m64 (a.k.a. "multilib"). TDM64 is a good MinGW-w64 distribution under Windows which fulfils this requirement.

Microsoft Visual C++ (Visual Studio) 2008. Only the full version will allow you to produce 64 bit or or 32+64 bit binaries.

Windows DDK build environment, which is freely available, through the use of the 'ddk_build.cmd' file. This will also produce all of 32, 64 or 32+64 bits binaries. Note that if you want to produce the applications that are compatible with all supported platforms from XP onwards, you will need to use the Windows XP WDK build environment for the 32bit builds and Windows Server 2003 build environment for the 64bit build.

The recommended development environment to compile the apps is the latest Windows WDK as it allows the building of a 32+64 bit compatible library.